# bootstrap carousel next and previous images not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

im working on bootstrap carousel which displaying images from database.Now i need to use this to display next and previous images as well in the same container.carousel is working fine but its not displaying next and prev images in it
i tried [This](https://www.codeply.com/go/EgUBayVMaj/bootstrap-carousel-with-next-prev-(partial)). But getting Image as given below.
Thank you for answer.

Output image is given.[Output im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXslf.jpg)

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
           
            $scope.vehicleImageList = {};
            $http.get('http://localhost:8087/mmg/api/v1/franchisevehicleimages/'+$scope.source, {
                headers: {
                    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx

                }
            }).then(function (results2) {
                $scope.vehicleImageList = results2.data.data;
            });
    
            $(function(){
                
                        $('.carousel-control').click(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#myCarousel').carousel( $(this).data() );
                        });
            })
            
            });
```

```css
.carousel,
.carousel-inner,
.carousel-inner > .item {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner:before {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 82%;
    left: 0;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-inner:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    left: 82%;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    background-color:#fff;
    z-index: 2;
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
    background: initial;
    width: 30%;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 10;
    top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- image carousel -->
  <div class="row">
  <div class="item form-group">
  <div class="col-md-11">  
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
          
          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item" ng-class="{active:!$index}" ng-repeat="list in vehicleImageList | unique:'name'">
              <img src="./src/images/{{list.name}}" alt="Vehicle" style="height:150px;width:250px">
              <!-- <div class="carousel-caption" style="color:black">
                  <h3 class="h3-responsive">Light mask</h3>
                  <p>First text</p>
            </div>  -->
          </div>
  
      
          <!-- Left and right controls -->
           <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>                            
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It easily can do using bootstrap.

see following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Carousel is working fine.. But what I need is, to display the previous and next images partly along with the current(active) image...

Comment: not clear your question..any clarification for that?

Comment: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/RKavve the demo is in this link, even code is there but im unable to do as per my req, i,e displaying images in db @sanduniYW